# Folders added to Git repository as binary files

Tags: git

I have committed some folders from my source tree to my Git repository and noticed that they have been added as binary files and all the files under these folders are missing from the repo. The folders are plugins for a Javascript WYSIWYG text editor and have java-esque names such as:

```
/static/js/aloha/plugins/com.gentics.aloha.plugins.Format/
```

Is there any way that the repository (it is a 3rd party, paid for repo on Assembla.com) has filtered the incoming commit and decided that they should be binaries?

I did nothing unusual to add them...

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'some message'
git push origin master
```

This is a really weird issue and I need to resolve it ASAP as I need all my code in the repo so I can schedule a Jenkins build to demonstrate to the client at the weekend. Has anybody got any ideas what is going on here? Is there anyway to view log files for Git so I can tell whether it is my Git client or the repo that is at fault?

Comment: The folders were been added as submodules as the lazy developers left their old .git folders in the downloadable source tree. Problem solved.

Comment: @Romain Patience mi amigo, you need to wait 2 days before you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was .git folders that were left in the downloaded archive which caused my Git client to treat parts of my source tree as submodules. Not complicated in the end.